# QuickBooks SyncStatus Issue

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

we are using QuickBooks desktop edition, facing a strange issue with QuickBooks Sales Receipt - Syncronised status and State code wrireBack Messages, Problem detail is as below in steps,

1. First we are fetching QuickBooks Sales Receipts with provided idSet

   ```
   Dim salesReceiptQuery = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SalesReceiptQuery() With {.Item1 = idset, _
                                                                             .Item1ElementName = Item1ChoiceType4.TransactionIdSet, _
                                                                             .IncludeTagElements = New String() {"SalesReceipt/Synchronized"}}

   Dim salesReceipts As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SalesReceipt) = Nothing

   Try
       salesReceipts = salesReceiptQuery.ExecuteQuery(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SalesReceipt)(QBContext)
   Catch ex As Exception
       Trace.WriteLine("SyncWatchDog Task - Exception: " & ex.Message)
   End Try
   ```

then we loop withe result to check  "salesReceipt.Synchronized = True", here we are getting some Sales Recepipt with  "salesReceipt.Synchronized = False".

1. Second step is we take all  Sales Recept Id with "salesReceipt.Synchronized = False", and query Quickbooks with below code,

   ```
    Dim syncStatusRequest As New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SyncStatusRequest() With {.NgIdSet = list.GetNgIdSetArray}

    Dim syncStatusResponse = DataServices.GetSyncStatus(syncStatusRequest)
   ```

   Here when we loop over syncStatusResponce to get "syncStatus.StateCode", we are getting 
   STATECODE    =1 , 
   STATEDESC=Synchronized,
   DESCRIPTION=(successful). Object created in QuickBooks. Equivalent to StateCode 8 (for object created in Data Services) 
   and 
   MESSAGECODE=40, 
   MESSAGEDESC=WRTB success,
   DESCRIPTION:The requests sent from Data Services to the QuickBooks company file were successfully synched into the company file.

we are not able to understand if Sales Receipt is salesReceipt.Synchronized = False, what is meaning of StateCode 1 and MessageCode 40.

Please suggest the solution,

Thanks & Regards,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to retrieve objects in a sync error state, by specifying the ErroredObjectsOnly="true" attribute.

If you get any object in the response, then try to see the sync status of those error-ed objects using status API,otherwise(success) call GetAll API on SalesReceipt to see if you are getting all those objects(as by default it returns objects which were successfully created).

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/syncstatus

You can ApiExplorer tool to test this use case.

Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

Comment: We are already checking the Errorstate before checking SynscStatus of SalesRecepit, thay are not in ErrorState,But in individual Sales Recipt Object -"salesReceipt.Synchronized = False", and in SyncStatusResponce - StateCode = 1, and MessageCode=40

Comment: can you share the SalesReceipt create XML. I'll try to reproduce this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you query some other retrieved records too retrieved from salesReceipt.Synchronized = False?
Check if they also have StateCode 1.
It might be an issue with the Synchronized filter not working and retrieving all data.

Comment: Yes.I have checked that. but it seems there is no issue in Synchronized filter.